# Pronunciar "mas" como "mais": poderia ser um arcaísmo?

Tags: fonologia, regionalismo, mudanças-históricas

Nalguns dialetos brasileiros, ocorre a mudança sonora ˈVs# → ˈVjs# (desde que "s" não seja sufixo): paz /ˈpajs/, mês /ˈmejs/, cruz /ˈkɾujs/, arroz /a.ˈhojs/, nós /ˈnɔjs/; compare com pás /ˈpas/, bônus /ˈbo.nus/, nos /nus/.

Porém, não me é claro se tal regra se aplicaria a "mas", pois é por vezes uma palavra átona, por vezes tônica. De qualquer jeito, muitos hoje confundem "mas" e "mais" na escrita.

Tanto "mais" quanto "mas" vêm do latim "magis" (segundo o Priberam), sugerindo que um estágio anterior da língua só tinha "mais".

Também, o dicionário da Real Academia Galega (https://academia.gal/dicionario) indica que os galegos escrevem só "mais", sem "mas". (O galego é próximo do português setentrional, e este influenciou falares brasileiros.)

---

**Questão**. Há algum dialeto brasileiro em que a pronúncia de "mas" como "mais" seja um arcaísmo, em vez do resultado duma mudança sonora que reunificou as duas palavras?

Answer (score 1):

A mudança sonora de "mas" para "mais" não é comum em dialetos brasileiros. O fenômeno que você descreveu, a alteração de ˈVs# para ˈVjs# em alguns dialetos, não costuma afetar a palavra "mas" nesse sentido.

O uso incorreto de "mas" e "mais" na escrita pode ser mais relacionado a questões de educação linguística e confusão entre as palavras do que a uma variação dialetal específica. Portanto, é menos provável que a pronúncia "mas" como "mais" seja um arcaísmo em algum dialeto brasileiro, mas sim mais associado a equívocos na escrita.

Comment: Muitos brasileiros falam mais para mas.

Answer (score 0):

> As palavras **mais** ou **mas têm sons iguais**, mas são escritas de
> formas diferentes e cada uma faz parte de uma classificação da
> morfologia. Seus significados no contexto também vão mudar dependendo
> da palavra usada.
>
> No dia a dia, no discurso informal, *é comum ouvir as pessoas falando
> “mais” quando, na verdade, querem se referir à expressão “mas” para
> dar sentido de oposição à frase. Por isso, é importante falar certo
> para **escrever adequadamente**.*

[ENEM](https://www.educamaisbrasil.com.br/enem/lingua-portuguesa/mais-ou-mas)

Procura ouvir os dois aqui (brasileiros e portugueses):

[mas](https://forvo.com/word/o_motorista_tentou_puxar_conversa%2C_mas_desistiu/#pt)
Na frase, O motorista tentou puxar conversa, mas desistiu.

Um dos falantes brasileiros diz claramente a palavra sem o som i e o outro diz a palavra com o som i. Então depende do falante.